# copy and paste with google spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to modify the script shown below, so that if re-run, it does not overwrite pre-existing data, but instead writes the rows under it.

(I use the google spreadsheet)

```
moveValuesOnly fonction () {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1 F1: H3 ');
source.copyTo (ss.getRange ("Feuil2 A1! '), {contentsOnly: true});
source.clear ();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This version will find the first empty row in the destination sheet, and copy the source data so it starts there.

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!F1:H3");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Feuil2");
  // Déterminer l'emplacement de la première ligne vide.
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();
}
```

Comment: How can I use this for specific columns? so lets say only column 2, 4 and 5 ?

Comment: this is removing the data from the original spreadsheet.  How do I just copy the info?

Comment: Delete "source.clear ();" from the script