# Automatically Copy Data Between Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I am looking for some help automating copying data between google sheets.

I have a sheet called "Current Data". This sheet has data in columns A-F(with headers).
Column A contains usernames. Columns B-F will have formulas which pulls data from Instagram.com using

=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(

I got the formulas from this website:
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/import-social-media-statistics/

There is another sheet called "Historical Data". This sheet contains the same columns as "Current Data" (A-F, with headers).
This sheet contains all data from the "Current Data" sheet, pasted daily.

**My Current Process:**

- Open Sheet Navigate to "Current Data" sheet, copy values from A2-FXXX
- Navigate to "Historical Data" sheet, scroll to next blank row, paste
  data.

I am looking to automate this and have it occur daily.

I am using this script to automatically update my IMPORTXML function. This works great.
[Periodically refresh IMPORTXML() spreadsheet function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872967/periodically-refresh-importxml-spreadsheet-function/33875957#33875957)

- I am copying the values from the Current Data sheet to the Historical
  Data sheet, using this script.
  [copy and paste with google spreadsheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725911/copy-and-paste-with-google-spreadsheet-script).

  - This script also works, but it is only copying the first line of data to the destination. The script is also wiping the data from the Current Data sheet.
  - I removed the "source.clear ();" from the code, but the
    data still gets wiped.

I also tried using this script, as some people mentioned users needed to use appendRow instead of copyTo. Still no luck with this code:

```
function moveValuesOnlyy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange("CurrentData!A2:F100");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("HistoricalData");
  destSheet.appendRow(source.getValues());
 }
```

In the end I am looking for the script to:

- Find and copy the data range from the "Current Data" sheet, starting with A2.
- Find next empty row on "Historical Data" sheet.
- Paste as values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Update your post with your exact script that is only giving you the first line (with your document names and things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function copyPaste() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('CurrentData');
  var dessh=ss.getSheetByName('HistoricalData');
  var srcrg=srcsh.getRange('A2:F100');
  var data=srcrg.getValues();
  var desrg=dessh.getRange(dessh.getLastRow() + 1,1,99,6);
  desrg.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: i know this has been here for a bit - but wondering if it's possible to reference a cell instead of having to hard code  A2:F100?