# How to Cut line from Sheet1 and Paste to Sheet2 if the date on a cell is 30+ days old?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can i automatically copy a row from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`, if a cell date on Sheet1 is 30+ days old, and then delete that row from `Sheet1`?

My intention is to make a backup on `Sheet2` of the rows on `Sheet1` that are 30+ days old.

The dates i need to check are Column `H4:H`.

This question below is almost same thing i need, except for the fact that i must have the date condition

[Automatically Copy Data Between Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269902/automatically-copy-data-between-google-sheets)

```
function copyPaste() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('CurrentData');
  var dessh=ss.getSheetByName('HistoricalData');
  var srcrg=srcsh.getRange('A2:F100');
  var data=srcrg.getValues();
  var desrg=dessh.getRange(dessh.getLastRow() + 1,1,99,6);
  desrg.setValues(data);
}
```

I am just beginner with google script, sorry if this sounds stupid. Thank you.

Here is the sheet i am working:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LlqzlkdB5q-xZMwX-_-UnT8NO-q6oIJz9WWb3JRfWC0/edit#gid=568293021

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. About `if a cell date on Sheet1 is 30+ days old, and then delete that row from Sheet1?`, where cell and row (or rows?) do you want to check in Sheet1? And also, where do you want to copy the row (or rows?) to Sheet2? I would like to think of the solution by correctly understanding your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: Column H3:H on Sheet1 stores dates. I want to copy that entire row to last empty row on Sheet2 IF date on Column H of Sheet1 is 30 or more days older from the actual date, and then remove that row from Sheet1. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that your issue had already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function move() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const csh=ss.getSheetByName('CurrentData')
  const hsh=ss.getSheetByName('HistoricalData')
  const cshsr=4;//start row for csh
  const crg=csh.getRange(cshsr,1,csh.getLastRow()-cshsr+1,csh.getLastColumn());
  const cvs=crg.getValues();
  const dt=new Date();
  const dtv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-30).valueOf();//thirty day threshold
  let d=0;
  cvs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(new Date(r[7]).valueOf()<dtv) {
      hsh.appendRow(r);//appends to bottom
      csh.deleteRow(i+cshsr-d++);//includes delete counter
    }
  });  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It did not work. No errors but nothing happened. Could you please check the live sheet? Thank you. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LlqzlkdB5q-xZMwX-_-UnT8NO-q6oIJz9WWb3JRfWC0/edit#gid=568293021

Comment: Try it again. I  used the wrong column for the dates

Comment: Now it is working, but looks like it is processing lines 1, 2 and 3. It need to process only line 4 on. Line 2 is being deleted on currentdata, and first line pasted to historical data is messed. Thanks!!!

Comment: I was curious about that because in your code your data range is A2:F100

Comment: Any way now you can pick whatever start row you wish with cshsr

Comment: Now it is pasting correctly, but it is still deleting line 2 during the process. The line 2 is not being pasted to hstorical data, but is being deleted from currentdata. Maybe the problem is at   `csh.deleteRow(i+2-d++);`

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedback I needed to change the last line in the code to contain the cshsr

Comment: Wow, very nice, its perfect!!! Youre a real pro man!!! Thank you very much!!! You deserve a lot of good things in life. Thanks for being so friendly and prestative!

Answer (score 1):

It gets a bit more complicated when you don't want to just copy all of the values from one sheet to another.  In the line in the code below, the `0` will need to correspond with the location of the date value in the sheet, keeping in mind that arrays start at 0 and ranges start at 1.  So, for example, if your date is in the third column of the spreadsheet, this line would look like this:

`var msback= new Date() - values[i][2]`

Hope this helps!

```
function moveifover30() {
  
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msperday = 1000*60*60*24 //milliseconds*seconds*minutes*hours

  //get both sheets
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('CurrentData')
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName('HistoricalData')
  
  //This gets the whole data range
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  
  //This gets the values from the data range
  var values = datarange.getValues();
  
  //This goes through the values array one by one and checks for the condition
  for (var i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
  
  //Date math is alwasy in milliseconds, so we can create a new date object and then subtract the date in the array which will get the difference in milliseconds
  if(values[i][0] && Object.prototype.toString.call(values[i][7]) === "[object Date]") { 
   var msback = new Date() - values[i][0]
  
   //number of milliseconds per day
    
   if(msback/msperday > 30) {
    
     sheet3.appendRow(values[i])
     sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 
     datarange.getLastColumn()).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS)
    }
   }
  
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but something is not right. Can you please take a look here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LlqzlkdB5q-xZMwX-_-UnT8NO-q6oIJz9WWb3JRfWC0/edit#gid=568293021

Comment: @LucasMatos, I modified the code in the script using my above example.  I can't test it on the example you provided since I don't have permissions to modify the other spreadsheet but I believe that the issue was that the first value in your date column in your example was not a date object.  I added a line to check if it's a valid date before running the code, and have also added the line to the code above.