# Excel Macro to Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

Trying to convert the following code written in Excel to work in google sheets.
Have clear contents working, but the paste formulas are not working well.

```
If Range("D8").Value = 1 Then
Worksheets("Input").Range("C4:C12").Copy
Worksheets("Wheat").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If

If Range("D8").Value = 2 Then
Worksheets("Input").Range("C4:C12").Copy
Worksheets("Barley").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If

If Range("D8").Value = 3 Then
Worksheets("Input").Range("C4:C12").Copy
Worksheets("Rye").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If

If Range("D8").Value = 4 Then
Worksheets("Input").Range("C4:C12").Copy
Worksheets("Canola").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If

If Range("D8").Value = 5 Then
Worksheets("Input").Range("C4:C12").Copy
Worksheets("Peas").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If

If Range("D8").Value = 6 Then
Worksheets("Input").Range("C4:C12").Copy
Worksheets("Oats").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If

If Range("D8").Value = 7 Then
Worksheets("Input").Range("C4:C12").Copy
Worksheets("Flax").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If

Range("C5").Value = Range("C5").Value + 1
Range("C10:C12").ClearContents
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the apps script code you've tried? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703176/4717755)

Comment: Please have a look at the Google Apps Script guides and references and try to write some code yourself. The community will be happy to help your solving questions to specific problems you might encounter.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the exact code you are looking for, but try it.

```
if(worksheets.getRange('D8').getValue()==1)
{
   var copysheet = worksheets.getRange("Input!C4:C12");
   copysheet.copyTo (worksheets.getRange ("Wheat!A1"), {contentsOnly: true});  
}            
if(worksheets.getRange('D8').getValue()==2)
{
   var copysheet = worksheets.getRange("Input!C4:C12");
   copysheet.copyTo (worksheets.getRange ("Barley!A1"), {contentsOnly: true});
}
if(worksheets.getRange('D8').getValue()==3)
{
   var copysheet = worksheets.getRange("Input!C4:C12");
   copysheet.copyTo (worksheets.getRange ("Rye!A1"), {contentsOnly: true});  
}            
if(worksheets.getRange('D8').getValue()==4)
{
   var copysheet = worksheets.getRange("Input!C4:C12");
   copysheet.copyTo (worksheets.getRange ("Canola!A1"), {contentsOnly: true});
}
if(worksheets.getRange('D8').getValue()==5)
{
   var copysheet = worksheets.getRange("Input!C4:C12");
   copysheet.copyTo (worksheets.getRange ("Peas!A1"), {contentsOnly: true});
}
if(worksheets.getRange('D8').getValue()==6)
{
   var copysheet = worksheets.getRange("Input!C4:C12");
   copysheet.copyTo (worksheets.getRange ("Oats!A1"), {contentsOnly: true});
}
if(worksheets.getRange('D8').getValue()==7)
{
   var copysheet = worksheets.getRange("Input!C4:C12");
   copysheet.copyTo (worksheets.getRange ("Flax!A1"), {contentsOnly: true});
}
   var value=worksheets.getRange("C5").getValue();
   worksheets.getRange("C5").setValue(value+1);
   var clearrange = worksheets.getRange("C10:C12").clear();
```

worksheets is the active spreadsheet.